# Call program from command line using alias

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

For easier usage, I want to be able to use an alias in the command line to call a programm.
Given a path to a programm like:

```
%program files%\Company\ZAP.exe`
```

I want to call it from the command line using:

```
ZAP -parameter1 -parameter2      // good
```

I **don't** want to use the way through a environment variable like this:

```
%ZAP% -parameter1 -parameter2    // bad
```

I also don't want to change the `%path%` environment variable.
If there's a way using the registry, that's ok for me.

So is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:** This should be a permanent alias that is 'installed' not manually but from my installation.

Comment: I have one dedicated directory for this kind of things that is in the `PATH` and I simply put a batch file there with the call to the real program (that also prevents cluttering the `PATH` with every directory that contains a program I want "on the path")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a batch file containing the following, call it `zap.bat` and place it in `c:\windows`

```
@echo off
"%program files%\Company\ZAP.exe" %*
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `doskey`.

```
doskey ZAP="%program files%\Company\ZAP.exe"
```

You'd be able to access the path by saying `ZAP`.  However, that wouldn't work inside a batch file.

---

EDIT: Another approach that makes the change permanent is to register an application by creating a registry entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`.

Please refer to [Application Registration (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#reg_app) for further information like path restriction.

Comment: This won't work once the command prompt is closed and re-opened.

Comment: workaround to make it work persistently: http://devblog.point2.com/2010/05/14/setup-persistent-aliases-macros-in-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe-using-doskey/